# Cast to inherited class from ArrayList of base class

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance, arraylist, casting

I have two classes A and B , where A is the base class and B is inherited from A.

```
Class A
{
    int foo=10;
}

Class B extends A
{
     int bar=100;
}
```

I declare an ArrayList of Class A and insert Class A and Class B objects into it.

My issue is when i attempt to get the Class B object which is in the ArrayList of Class A and then cast it to Class B as follows

```
B foobar = (B)ArrayListOfClassA.get(IndexOfClassB).
```

The value of bar in Object B is undefined.

> How do i get the value of Object B from the ArrayList of Class A ???

Comment: This is worrisome; why do you intend to store two barely related objects into the same list?

Comment: can you put up your actual code here, this thing should not happen

Comment: @Makoto is saying right. you can check with instanceof operator first.

Comment: @Prashant - `instanceof` does *compile time* check. He needs to use `getClass()==`

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to typecast instances like this. Check for type before calling any method / field using `getClass()==`.

```
if(myInstance.getClass()==B.class)
//print myInstance.bar
```

Note : This is not a good design because you are *breaking* the most important thing generics was introduced for (and you can see what happens when you do that)

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand what you need exactly, but i tried to write some test and it is works fine

```
@Test
public void test() {
    class A {
        int foo = 10;
    }

    class B extends A {
        int bar = 100;
    }

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (r.nextBoolean()) {
            list.add(new A());
        } else {
            list.add(new B());
        }
    }

    ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
    ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
    for (Object o: list) {
        if (o instanceof B) {
            listB.add((B) o);
        } else if (o instanceof A) {
            listA.add((A) o);
        }
    }
}
```